# Effect of card code field CIM payment profiles

Tags: authorize.net

I am using authorize.net CIM method to create customer profile & payment profiles using soap service in asp.net (C#) here I want to confirm that , Currently card code field is not set as mandatory for my merchant payment form & card code validation filter is  not configured in merchant account settings but I can able to create payment profiles regardless of card code parameter using CreateCustomerPaymentProfile method of soap service .
Now, I just want to know that ,If I set card code field in merchant payment form as required field & enable card code validation filter in setting  then whether I need to pass card code field during payment profile creation & what will be effect of making card code as required field in merchant payment form & enabling card code validation in setting on existing created CIM profiles ?

Please kindly assist.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If a card code is submitted as part of profile creation and validationMode is set to livemode, the card code will be used as part of the $0 transaction.  However, the card code is not stored with the profile.

When using a payment profile for a transaction, you can also require the user to enter the card code and when included will be used with the transaction.